# Can I make the Keyboard Viewer more readable

Tags: keyboard, accessibility, macos

I am using the **Keyboard Viewer** in recorded video screenshots to demonstrate the action of keystrokes on an app.
The keyboard window is small, the produced video is compressed, and as a result it is very hard for many people in the audience to perceive what keys are pressed during the presentation (pressed keys are outlined in dark brown/purple on a black background).

The previous UX for the **Keyboard Viewer** was a lot more accessible and legible.

I am not expressing an opinion - tools like [WebAIM](https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/) give this color combination [a Contrast Ratio Fail rating across all three categories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aegK.jpg), with a very low 2.02:1 contrast rating against the surrounding background color.

### **Current Keyboard Viewer on Catalina:**

[image]

<sub>Can you tell which keys are pressed? I didn't think so</sub>

### **Previous Keyboard Viewer on High Sierra:**

[image]

<sub>Can you tell which keys are pressed? Yes you can! Yes you can!</sub>

### Is there a way to use the more accessible, gray Keyboard Viewer on Catalina?

*Given that Apple has always had [very inclusive Accessibility Guidelines](https://www.apple.com/accessibility/), I am hoping that I am missing a setting somewhere and that this poor UX decision can be reversed.*

Comment: Is it mode-dependant? I don't have Catalina to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Catalina Keyboard Viewer, click the Gear icon in the upper right corner of the window. This opens a pop-up window where you can select the Appearance setting of the Keyboard View window to either Dark or Light, independent of the System Appearance setting:

[image: Dark Mode]

[image: Ligt Mode]

- When you choose Dark Mode, a pressed key is outlined in red.
- When you choose Light Mode, a pressed key is outlined in red in addition to having a grey overlay, which is what you are looking for.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks a lot. Very confused as to why design rules are not applied by designers when creating dark mode interfaces... I have the same problem with the dark mode in Adobe apps, grey text over grey backgrounds... what a nightmare. Thanks anyways.